# Why do YouTube videos become greyish in Chrome if hardware acceleration is disabled?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, video-codecs, hardware-acceleration, nvidia-graphics-card

**Update: One of the tests has shown that the problem persists on certain devices even if the hardware acceleration is enabled.** The 4 screenshots below were taken on Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT240M.

[image: YouTube screenshots compared with/without Hardware Acceleration in Chrome]

[image: YouTube screenshots compared with/without Hardware Acceleration in Chrome]

I've just made some tests, see the results below.

**White as expected:**

- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ON.
- Windows 10, Firefox, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ON.
- Windows 10, Firefox, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC OFF.
- Windows 10, Edge, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ?.
- Windows 10, IE11, nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC ?.
- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT630M, HACC ON.
- Windows  7, Firefox, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, HACC ON.
- Windows  7, Firefox, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, HACC OFF.
- Android 5.0.1, Chrome, Adreno 320, HACC ?.
- Android 5.0.1, YouTube, Adreno 320, HACC ?.

**Grey bug:**

- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT240M, HACC OFF.
- Windows 10, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m (64-bit), nVidia GeForce GT630M, HACC OFF.
- Windows  7, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, **HACC ON**.
- Windows  7, Chrome 47.0.2526.111 m, SyS Mirage 3 Graphics, HACC OFF.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why the downvote? I've added more details to make the question better quality, and removed it from StackOverflow, as it was marked as off-topic and was recommended to be moved here to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding issue:

> Digital video is typically encoded in a YCbCr format. YCbCr is a family of color spaces (YV12, YUY2, etc), that encode color information (chroma) separately from brightness information (luma).
>
> Thus when converting a YCbCr colorspace to RGB, the correct standard (BT.601 or BT.709) must be used and the correct range (TV or PC levels) must be used.
>
> The above is not always done correctly. It can go wrong with certain combinations of video renderers, video resolutions and graphics driver settings.
>
> The video looks washed out and the colors are not vivid. Black is displayed as dark gray. White is displayed as light gray.

**References**

- [Video playback issues](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/video-playback-issues.html)
- [Luminance levels](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Luminance_levels)
- [Stereoscopic Multiplexers (pdf)](http://www.3dtv.at/downloads/stereoscopicplayerstereoscopicmultiplexersda2005.pdf)
- [A Glimpse into Video Processing (pdf)](http://www.mime.univ-paris8.fr/PGronlier_2012-10-22.pdf)
- [Chromium Source: Software Rendering List](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json)
- [Media Data Atom Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html)